# EEG Emotiv - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Im trying to run the eeglogger or the emotiv Toolbox to record some samples of the EEG Emotiv, but it always show some errors:

> Error in EmotivEEG (line 73)
>                   [notfound,warnings] = loadlibrary('edk.dll','edk.h');
>                   %#ok

and If I follow some instructions of forums I can get this:

> Warning:
>   'EE_COGNITIV}EE_EmotivSuite_t;typedefenumEE_ExpressivAlgo_enum{EXP_NEUTRAL=0x0001'
>   exceeds MATLAB's maximum name length of 63 characters and has been
>   truncated to
>   'EE_COGNITIV}EE_EmotivSuite_t;typedefenumEE_ExpressivAlgo_enum{E'.
>
> > In edk_proto at 11   In loadlibrary at 379   In eeglogger at 84  Error loading library intermediate output follows. The actual error is
> >     at the end of this output.
> >
> > ---
>
> No match found for enum value expression EE_ExpressivAlgo_t in
>   0x0800}EE_ExpressivAlgo_t;typedefenumEE_AffectivAlgo_enum{AFF_EXCITEMENT=0x0001 expression ignored. Found on line 840 of input from line 656 of file
>   c:\users\marcelo\documents\matlab\EmoStateDLL.h
>
> No match found for enum value expression EE_AffectivAlgo_t in
>   0x0010}EE_AffectivAlgo_t;typedefenumEE_CognitivAction_enum{COG_NEUTRAL=0x0001
>   expression ignored. Found on line 840 of input from line 656 of file
>   c:\users\marcelo\documents\matlab\EmoStateDLL.h
>
> No match found for enum value expression EE_CognitivAction_t in
>   0x2000}EE_CognitivAction_t;typedefenumEE_SignalStrength_enum{NO_SIGNAL=0
>   expression ignored. Found on line 840 of input from line 656 of file
>   c:\users\marcelo\documents\matlab\EmoStateDLL.h
>
> No match found for enum value expression EE_Event_t in
>   16|32|64|128|256|512|1024}EE_Event_t;typedefenumEE_ExpressivEvent_enum{EE_ExpressivNoEvent=0
>   expression ignored. Found on line 1993 of input from line 1166 of file
>   C:\Users\Marcelo\Documents\MATLAB\edk.h
>   ********* Error using loadlibrary (line 423)
>
> There was an error running the loader file.  Use the mfilename option
>   to produce a file that you can debug and fix if needed.  Please report
>   this error to the MathWorks so we can improve this function.
>
> Error in eeglogger (line 84)
>       [nf, w] = loadlibrary('edk','edk',  'addheader', 'EmoStateDLL', 'addheader', 'edkErrorCode');
>
> Caused by:
>       Error using struct
>       Invalid field name "EE_COGNITIV}EE_EmotivSuite_t;typedefenumEE_ExpressivAlgo_enum{E"

I put all files needed in the same folder

Anyone know how can I be able to use emotiv with matlab? and why everyone has the same problems but no confirmed solution?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as i wrote before and got punished for it, i had the same problem, but i solve it, first of all are you using matlab 32 bits?? otherwise it wont work anything, im using matlab 32 bit 2013, you also need visual studio 32 bit compiler 2010 or older,you need to have all the .dll files on the same folder as well as the edk.h file and set the proper c compiler suing mex -setup, i use the files share by [akshaybabloo](https://github.com/akshaybabloo/EmoMat) to acces the emotiv and its working so far.

Note: You must have a research edition Emotiv Epoc otherwise you wont be able to access EEG raw data .